# How to make a dropdown menu show content

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a website which I will have a dropdown menu that, depend on what is selected within it, will show different content. I saw [this][1] code but it didn't help, as for some reason it didn't work on my computer. Also, that code isn't exactly what I was looking for.

```js
    $('#myPRODUVTS').on('change', function() {
 fruit = $(this).val();
    if (fruit == 'Apple') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.45');
    }
    if (fruit == 'Orange') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.50');
    }
    if (fruit == 'Mango') {
        $('#Price').val('£0.65');
    }
});
```

Comment: in where would you like to show the value of the dropdown? could you please post your code including your `html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will work

```js
 $(function() {
   $('#myPRODUVTS').change( function() {
   fruit = $(this).val();
      if (fruit == 'Apple') {
          $('#Price').val('£0.45');
          $('#PriceDiv').text('£0.45');
      }
      if (fruit == 'Orange') {
          $('#Price').val('£0.50');
          $('#PriceDiv').text('£0.50');
      }
      if (fruit == 'Mango') {
          $('#Price').val('£0.65');
          $('#PriceDiv').text('£0.65');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myPRODUVTS">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
</select>

<input id="Price">
<div id="PriceDiv">
```